# ICS - menu item text cut off?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm using the standard onCreateOptionsMenu, but on my Nexus w/ICS, when I tap the vertical menu button in the upper right corner, the dropdown context menu is 3/4 off the screen. Basically, I only see the first 3-4 letters in each menu items text.

Any ideas? Maybe I didn't get that memo!! I dont want to setup an ActionBar. I'd think by default, this should work fine?!?

Again, its pretty much standard menu code for < 3.0 SDK.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

if (!isPro()) {

    // add menu for ad-free Banner (launches Market)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_pro, menu);
}
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

return true;
}
```

Using standard menu XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_help"
    android:title="@string/menu_help"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:icon="@drawable/email"
    android:title="@string/menu_email"/>
```

[image]

Comment: show us the xml layouts.I think the problem may exist there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant really say why its cutting off on the top, but I added this to my manifest.xml.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
```

This basically reverts the style back to 2.x menus and places the vertical "dots" on the bottom right.

[image]

I actually prefer this over the default compatibility because I still  have my icon menus as opposed to plain text-only dropdown menus.

I'd still like to know why the "default" conversion of my menu is screwed  up though if anyone can chime in I'll award the solution to that person! (=

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to you manifest:

```
supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
```